# If each Ci is a closed subset in their topology, is it closed in the countably infinite product topology

Tags: general-topology

I have just learned about countably infinite product topology and I am already confused by the way it is defined. The definition I was given: The product space, ∏(Xi,τi), consists of the product ∏Xi with the topology τ having as its basis the family B={∏Oi:Oi ∈τi and Oi=Xi for all but a finite number of i.

This is not what I expected the basis to be. Of course, I learned about the box topology which is what one would expect the basis to be but the text stated that the reason why the product topology is not defined that way is because the box topology lacks many good properties we want.

So if we take a familiar example like R^infinity where R is the real numbers, a basic open set would be something like R x R x (0,2) x (6,10) x R x R x (9,10) x R....with the rest all Rs. And another basic open set would be something like (0,2) x (6,10) x R x R x R....with the rest all Rs. As long as all but finite number of open sets in the product are Rs, it would be consider a basic open set right? I know there is a good reason why the countably infinite product topology is defined this way and I hope to learn the reason soon, but does that mean a set like (0,2) x (0,2) x (0,2) x ...with the rest all (0,2) would not even be considered an open set?

Now having said all that, the problem I have to work on is: For each i∈N, let Ci be a closed subset of a topological space (Xi,τi). Prove that ∏Ci is a closed subset of ∏(Xi,τi).

I am pretty this is the product topology and not the box topology. But I don't see how this statement could be true. If we go back to a familiar example R^infinity, lets take the infinite countable product of [0,4]x[0,4]x[0,4]x[0,4]x[0,4]x[0,4]x[0,4]x[0,4]....with the rest all being [0,4]. So the complement of this should be open in the product topology, and the complement of each is (-infinity,0)u(4,infinity) in R. But the text just said all basic open sets cannot be of this form, so there is no way that is open in the product topology, so I am probably misunderstanding something.

Comment: The answer to your first question is *yes*: the set $\prod_{n\ge 0}U_n$, where each $U_n=(0,2)$, is not open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $C_n=[0,4]$, and let $C=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}C_n$. Then

$$\Bbb R^\infty\setminus C\ne\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}(\Bbb R\setminus C_n)\,,$$

so the fact that $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}(\Bbb R\setminus C_n)$ is not open tells you nothing about whether $C$ is closed or not.

Suppose that $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in\Bbb R^\infty$; when is $x$ **not** in $C$? In order for $x$ to be in $C$, we must have $x_n\in[0,4]$ for **every** $n\in\Bbb N$. Thus, $x\in\Bbb R^\infty\setminus C$ exactly when there is **at least one** $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\notin[0,4]$. If for each $k\in\Bbb N$ we set

$$U_k=\left\{\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in\Bbb R^\infty:x_k\notin[0,4]\right\}\,,$$

then $\Bbb R^\infty\setminus C=\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}U_k$. If each of the sets $U_k$ is open, then so is their union, and therefore $C$ is closed.

And in fact each $U_k$ is even a **basic** open set in the product topology on $\Bbb R^\infty$; can you see how to write $U_k$ in the form $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}V_n$, where each $V_n$ is open in $\Bbb R$, and all but finitely many of the $V_n$ are equal to $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes a lot of sense. So taking the specific example you gave, U1  be something like (-infinity,0)u(4,infinity) x R x R x R...and we can do the same for each of the Ui. But U1 can also be (-infinity,0)u(4,infinity) x (5,6) x R x R...so each Ui can be written in an infinite number of ways right? Do we always get the same space if we take the union of all of them?

Comment: @willyx888: You’re welcome! To get $U_1$ you need to use your first idea, which is exactly right: using the second one, with the $(5,6)$ factor, leaves out some of the points that have $x_1\notin[0,4]$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: show that $\prod C_i= \bigcap  π_i^{-1}(C_i)$ where $π_i: \prod X_i \to X_i $ is the i-th projection

Answer (score 0):

$C_1\times C_2\times C_3...=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (C_1\times C_2\times C_3...\times C_n\times \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\times ...)$ and intersection of closed sets is always closed.